# how to initialize a fortran character to 255 without warning from ACHAR

Tags: fortran

I have some Fortran code that packages up bytes for the GRIB2 meteorological format.

For some test code, I need to initialize an array of character. I do this with this code:

```
  ! Storage for the grib2 message we are constructing.
  integer, parameter :: lcgrib = 191
  character, dimension(lcgrib) :: cgrib
  ! This is the GRIB2 message we expect to get.
  character(kind = int8) :: expected_cgrib(lcgrib) = (/  achar( 71), achar( 82),&
       & achar( 73), achar( 66), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  2), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(191), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar( 21), achar(  1), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  7), achar(  0), achar(  4), achar(  2), achar( 24),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  7), achar(229), achar( 11), achar( 13),&
       & achar( 15), achar( 59), achar( 59), achar(  1), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  8), achar(  2),&
       & achar(  1), achar(  2), achar(  3), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar( 72), achar(  3), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  4), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  1), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  1), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  2), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  2), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar( 45), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar( 91), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar( 55), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(101), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  5),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  5), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar( 34), achar(  4),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar( 12), achar( 59), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  1), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  2), achar(  1),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar( 21), achar(  5), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  4), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar( 65), achar( 48), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  1), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  8), achar(  0),&
       & achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  6), achar(  6),&
       & achar(255), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  9),&
       & achar(  7), achar(  0), achar(  1), achar(  1), achar(  2),&
       & achar( 55), achar( 55), achar( 55), achar( 55) /)
```

I am using the achar() intrinsic function to convert the type of my integer constants into characters.

The problem is, this generates a warning with GNU gfortran:

```
   84 |        & achar(255), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  0), achar(  9),&
      |               1
Error: Argument of ACHAR function at (1) outside of range [0,127] [-Werror=surprising]
```

So what is happening is that one of my integer needed to initialize the character array is over 127, so not specified by ASCII.

Is there a way to avoid this warning, without explicitly turning it off?

Is there a way to initialize a character array in fortran with a string of numbers that are one-byte unsigned integers?

Comment: The meaning of `achar(255)` isn't defined by Fortran, so you certainly can't portably use that result. Given that, why do you want to use it, and what do you desire the result to be? If you do want to use it, why are you keen to avoid turning off the error/warning?  What is wrong with using `char` instead of `achar`?

Comment: (With `-Werror=surprising` you're explicitly asking for gfortran to warn about this case, and for that warning to present as an error. If you don't want that, don't ask for it.)

Comment: `achar` is there specifically for ASCII characters. If you just need to set the byte to some numeric value, use `char()`.